# Graphics.DrawIcon() method displays mirror image of the icon when RTL is enabled

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, custom-controls, right-to-left

I need to create a custom form that resembles the look and feel of the Microsoft Form.

Currently I am working on form icon customization.

I have used the below code to draw the icon.

```
 if (form.ShowIcon)
        {
            int x = 10,y = 10;
            Rectangle iconRect = new Rectangle(x, y, 16, 16);
            Icon icon = new Icon(form.Icon, 16, 16);
            g.DrawIcon(icon, iconRect);
        }
```

This works correctly.

But while enabling the RTL for the form, the form icon got a mirror effect. But in Microsoft Form the icon looks similar in both RTL enabled and disabled cases.

You can see the difference between my custom form and the Microsoft Form when enabling RTL in the below image.

[image]

2nd one is the Microsoft Form. 1st one is created by me, which displays the mirrored image of the icon.

I need to draw the icon same as the Microsoft Form.

Please share your suggestion for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If i use your code its not backwards... so its not in the code you are showing

Comment: omg. Then where I should check? Is it correct for you in both RTL enabled and disabled cases.?

Comment: Yes its the yellow block on the right in both cases, why do you repaint the icon though?

Comment: I have override the WndProc() method and process the WM_NCPAINT to draw the caption bar. So that, I have to paint all the elements inside the caption bar.  Is it possible to display the icon without repainting it.?

Comment: Im not sure if thats possible if you catch the paint process

Comment: okay. Thanks so much for you concern @EpicKip

Comment: When you ask for RTL layout then `g` is initialized differently.  ScaleTransform(-1, 1) was applied to it to get stuff to draw RTL, and LayoutTransform to put 0 in the upper right corner.  You'll have to use ScaleTransform + LayoutTransform yourself to correct.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry to say. I can't able to understand. Can you please explain your answer.?

Comment: Hans' advice was actually straightforward. Nothing special to 'understand' there. Just try it!! The methods he mentions are from the e.Graphics object class..